# Difference Between Latent Dirichlet Assignment (LDA) and Discrete Linear Analysis (LDA)

Tags: r, terminology

I have been studying some concepts of multivariate statistics and came across two models with the same name and very similar, but with different names. It makes me think they are the same. Can anyone help me differentiate them?

Comment: This might help: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B978012804291500009X

Comment: What is Discrete linear analysis? Do you mean [Linear discriminant Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis)? If so, they are very different. Starting from the first being a unsupervised algorithm and the second is supervised, and either describe a completely different process.